# SQL71508:The model already has an element that has the same name

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a CLR function in my project:
I Defined the function as a static method of a class in a language supported by the .NET Framework. Then, compiled the class to build an assembly.

```
[SqlFunction]
public static SqlString InsertCampaignRecipients(SqlString url)
{
    var rowData = string.Empty;
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var response = client.GetAsync(new Uri(url.Value)).Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            if (result.IndexOf(@"""Exception"":null}") > 0) //success
            {
                rowData = "success";
            }
            else
            {
                rowData = string.Empty;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            rowData = string.Empty;
        }
    }
    return rowData;
}
```

Then I created the function that references the registered assembly by using the CREATE FUNCTION statement:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[InsertCampaignRecipients] (@url NVARCHAR (4000) NULL)
RETURNS NVARCHAR (4000)
AS
  EXTERNAL NAME [SmartTouch.CRM.SqlClrDb].[UserDefinedFunctions].[InsertCampaignRecipients]
```

And I have an error:

> SQL71508: The model already has an element that has the same name
>   dbo.InsertCampaignRecipients

But if I rename my SQL function the error is gone. What's the problem?

Comment: Umm, there is already an other object called `InsertCampaignRecipients`? At least that's what the error suggests and that renaming helps also backs that.

Comment: Perhaps ALTER FUNCTION ....  assuming InsertCampaignRecipients is the pre-existing function

Comment: Sometimes this happens due to a glitch in VS. You should be able to fix it by clearing the bin and restarting VS.

Answer (score 0):

Object with the same name already exists. You can find what it is like this:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.objects o WHERE o.name ='InsertCampaignRecipients'
```

Comment: Yes, I have one object 'InsertCampaignRecipients' in my DB with type_desc CLR_SCALAR_FUNCTION. Is it not my SQL function?